# Was bedeutet: "Das geht sich nicht aus"?

Tags: meaning, phrase, idiom, austrian

Die Phrase "Das geht sich nicht aus" ist denke ich österreichisch? Ich bin Muttersprachler und hatte es davor noch nie gehört. Kann jemand helfen?

Comment: Danke für die Frage: Als Österreicher wär' ich nie auf die Idee gekommen dass das nicht im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum verbreitet ist ;-)

Comment: Ist nicht jeder Mensch Muttersprachler? Es daher noch nie gehört zu haben ist daher auch widersinnig. Du hast es dennoch nie gehört, nämlich weil es nur in Österreich verbreitet ist. Österreicher sind aber auch Muttersprachler.

Comment: Es ist immer wieder überraschend für einen Österreicher wie mich zu erfahren, wie wenig Deutsche über österreichisches Deutsch wissen, während so gut wie jeder Österreicher neben seiner eigenen Muttersprache (österreichisches Deutsch) genau gleich gut auch noch deutsches Deutsch versteht. Gleichzeitig ärgert es mich auch, dass viele Deutsche offenbar der Meinung sind, deutsches Deutsch wäre irgendwie höherwertiger als österreichisches Deutsch. - Was ich über österreichisches Deutsch gesagt habe, gilt sinngemäß auch für schweizerisches Hochdeutsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich finde es aber auch überraschend, dass man sich über so etwas ärgern kann. Wie viel Schweizerdeutsch verstehen Sie als Österreicher denn? Einer Sprachen einen Wert zuzuweisen finde ich auch falsch. Vermutlich liegt die hohe Verbreitung des Hochdeutschen an den entsprechenden Fernsehsendern.

Comment: Hier eine Videoinstallation zu  [geht sich aus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIfIYt26yU4) und [geht sich nicht aus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgreeUKQOts)

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Ging mir auch so als ich nach Deutschland gezogen bin. Hier noch einer: Wenn du nem Deutschen (selbst in Stuttgart im Süden) sagst "Ich hab das um 5 Euro gekauft.", dann fragt er zurück "*Um* 5 Euro? Ja wie viel Euro jetzt genau!?" Die sagen da konsequent *für*.

Comment: Liebe Österreicher-innen*,
Da scheint etwas passive Aggressivität und ein latenter Minderwertigkeitskomplex mitzuschwingen. Kennt sich ein Holsteiner mit Eigenheiten des fränkischen Deutsch aus? Kennt sich jeder Sachse mit Redewendungen aus dem Pfälzischen Deutsch aus? Von daher, Herr Schölnast, brauchen Sie sich nicht zu ärgern, wenn nicht-österreichisch Deutsche nicht jede Formulierung aus dem österreichischen Deutsch kennen. Jeder deutsche Dialekt hat seine Berechtigung, nicht alles wird überall im deutschen Sprachraum verstanden.

Comment: @AnselmEgloff: Sie verwechseln Dialekte mit Varietäten. Auch in Österreich werden viele verschiedene Dialekte gesprochen, aber österreichisches Deutsch ist neben deutschen Deutsch und schweizerischen Deutsch eine der drei Standard-Varietäten der deutschen Sprache. Alle drei Varietäten sind gleichwertig und alle drei sind Hochsprachen. Den Ausdruck »das geht sich aus« kann man in Tageszeitungen lesen, und man kann ihn von Nachrichtensprechern im Fernsehen hören. Das ist keine Dialekt-Phrase, sondern, im Gegensatz zu fränkischen und pfälzischen Dialekten, Hochdeutsch, das in Schulen gelehrt wird

Comment: Wenn man etwas Russisch kann, so wird man diese Phrase verstehen (auch wenn diese nicht in Deutschland ueblich ist): "это не выйдет" heisst woertlich soviel wie "es geht sich nicht aus".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

"Sich ausgehen" auf Österreichisch ([laut Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreichisches_Deutsch) umgangssprachlich auch in Bayern) bedeutet "passen", "klappen", "(gerade noch) hinbekommen".

"Das geht sich nicht aus" würde ich mit "Das haut nicht hin" oder "Das klappt nicht" übersetzen.

Comment: Für jemanden der längerer zeit in Bayern arbeitet ist es auf jeden Fall verständlich.

Comment: Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausgehen) kennt auch "sich ausgehen": `Verb "ausgehen". Beispiel: es geht sich aus (österreichisch umgangssprachlich für es reicht, passt)`

Answer (score 21):

Es bedeutet zu wenig Platz im zeitlichen oder örtlichen Sinn:

> Wenn wir erst um 10 Uhr weggehen, geht es sich nicht aus, dass wir den Zug erreichen.
>
> Du willst in dieser kleinen Parklücke einparken? Das geht sich doch niemals aus!

Answer (score 20):

Das könnte man mit

- *es reicht nicht (ganz)*
- *es klappt nicht (ganz)*
- *es wird nicht (mehr) funktionieren*

Impliziert wird hier, dass zum Erfolg nicht sehr viel fehlen würde bzw. dass es zeitlich knapp ist.

Sehr häufig hört man die Redewendung auch in der Sportberichterstattung des österreichischen Rundfunks, zum Beispiel (Livekommentar während eines Skirennens):

> "Lindsey Vonn nähert sich der Ziellinie. Sie hat im unteren Streckenabschnitt einige Fehler gemacht. Die Bestzeit geht sich für sie wohl nicht aus."

Answer (score 7):

Ich stimme @splattnes wunderbarer Definition zu:

- es reicht nicht (ganz)
- es klappt nicht (ganz)
- es wird nicht (mehr) funktionieren

möchte aber ergänzen: diese Phrase schreibt  niemandem die Schuld zu. Es gibt ja gar keine handelnden Personen, nur das abstrakte Faktum, dass es sich halt nicht ausgeht.  Nicht mal "die Umstände" sind schuld.

ein paar alternative Formulierungen die den gleichen Sachverhalt berschreiben:

- **Du** hast zu wenig Stoff gekauft | das geht sich nicht aus
- Das kriegen **wir** nicht mehr rechzeitig hin | das geht sich nicht aus
- **Die Bahn** war wieder mal verspätet, ich erreich den anschlusszug nicht
  | das geht sich nicht aus

Answer (score 4):

Ich bin Österreicher, und mir war lange Zeit nicht bewusst, dass »sich ausgehen« nicht im ganzen Sprachraum verbreitet ist. Ich wüsste auch gar nicht, was ich in bestimmten Situationen stattdessen sagen sollte. Ich versuche daher, die Verwendung anhand von Beispielen zu erläutern:

> *(Mutter, nervös und hektisch):* Komm, mach schneller, zieh dich schneller an, damit wir endlich weg können. Der Bus fährt schon in sieben Minuten, und du trödelst hier so langsam herum.
>   *(Kind, völlig entspannt):* Eh noch sieben Minuten? Aber **das geht sich** ja eh noch locker **aus**.

Hier ist die Mutter der Ansicht, dass Eile geboten ist, weil sie und ihr Kind sonst den Bus verpassen könnten. Das Kind meint aber, dass sieben Minuten eine ausreichende Zeit sind, um ganz ohne Stress noch andere Schuhbänder in die Schuhe einzufädeln, und um ohne Hast den richtigen Schal auszuwählen.

Anders Beispiel:

> *(Frau, im Möbelhaus):* Glaubst du, dass dieser Schrank wirklich in unsere Nische im Vorzimmer passt? Willst du nicht lieber daheim mal die Breite ausmessen, bevor wir uns etwas kaufen, das dann nicht rein passt?
>   *(Mann):* Mach dir keine Sorgen, Schatzi, ich habe dafür einen Blick. **Das geht sich** ganz sicher **aus**. Der Schrank passt sicher in die Nische.

Das Ehepaar steht im Möbelgeschäft vor einem Schrank, der zuhause in eine Nische platziert werden soll, deren Breite niemand vorher ausgemessen hat. Die Frau hält es für klug, erst Maß zu nehmen, und erst dann gegebenenfalls den Schrank zu kaufen. Der Mann hingegen ist der Meinung, die Breite der Nische exakt mit der Breite des Schrankes vergleichen zu können, was ihm als Grundlage für eine Kaufentscheidung reicht.

Drittes Beispiel:

> *(Kunde, an der Supermarktkassa, in der Geldbörse kramend):* Augenblick, ich hab's gleich. 2 - 4 - 5; Moment, 5,20 - 5,25. Was macht's nochmal aus?
>   *(Kassiererin, gelangweilt):* 6,83
>   *(Kunde):* Ach, Mist, **das geht sich nicht aus**. (Räumt die Münzen wieder in die Geldbörse.) Dann zahle ich bitte mit Bankomat.

Der Kunde will an der Kassa den offenen Betrag mit Münzen begleichen, stellt dann aber fest, dass sein Bargeldvorrat nicht ausreicht. Er zahlt stattdessen mit seiner Bankomatkarte.

(»Kassa« ist ein in Österreich sehr übliches Synonym für Kasse)
(»Bankomat« ist die in Österreich übliche Bezeichnung für Geldautomaten. Die Karte, mit der man an einem Bankomaten Geld beheben kennt, heißt in Österreich daher »Bankomatkarte«; selbst dann, wenn man damit kein Geld behebt, sondern damit im Supermarkt bezahlt)