# What is the correct form of past tense of "sich ausgehen"

Tags: translation, phrase, verb, austrian, past-participle

I'm looking for a form of the verb *sich ausgehen* in the past sense, close to the meaning of

> We didn't make it (because of time constraints) yesterday anymore.

I was wondering if I could say something like

> Es hat sich gestern nicht mehr (zeitlich) ausgegangen.

Is that correct / should one rather use *sein* like they write in the dictionary or is this formulation completely wrong and there is a better one?

Comment: "Es geht sich aus" is an Austrian colloquial expression (according to Duden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausgehen )

Comment: As you probably know, *sein* is used to construct the Perfekt of verbs of direction/movement, *haben* for other verbs. Of course there are cases of doubt. (As a recent non-directional metaphor based on directional *(aus-)gehen*, *sich ausgehen* is such a case of doubt.) In these, *haben* generally wins in the North of Germany and *sein* generally wins in the Southern German-speaking regions. "Es hat sich nicht ausgegangen" is wrong because it combines an Austriacism with the Northern way of forming the Perfekt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct form is

> Es ist sich gestern nicht mehr ausgegangen.

But note that this is very colloquial and probably not understood outside of Bavaria and Austria.

Comment: somehow that sounded strange to me, but seems the grammar book is right :) i live in austria so it's more than ok if it's understood here ;)

Comment: @ladybug: ["Sich ausgehen" ... bedeutet "passen", "klappen", "(gerade noch) hinbekommen"](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/was-bedeutet-das-geht-sich-nicht-aus).

Comment: I lived in Austria for a few years, and I think the claim that *sich ausgehen* is *very* colloquial is wrong, at least for Vienna. I heard this all the time, including on television, from employees in shops, and from academics at Vienna University.

Comment: PS: But it is definitely true that most Germans, even from the south-west, will be puzzled at first. Not sure about Bavarians. I have never heard it in Bavaria, but they may have more exposure to Austrian German.

Comment: @HansAdler: I moved from Vienna to Stuttgart, the South of Germany, with 26 for a physics PhD and was totally confused when I accidentally discovered that people wouldn't understand me when I say "Das geht sich nicht aus." From talking to people at home later, I can confirm that the vast majority of Viennese people are unaware that this grammar isn't also German German. Another example would be the Viennese "I habe es um 5 Euro gekauft". Germans would respond "*Um* 5 Euro? Ja wie viel Euro jetzt genau?!"

Answer (score 2):

I'd translate using "ausreichen":

```
We didn't make it (because of time constraints) yesterday anymore.

Es hat gestern (zeitlich) leider nicht mehr gereicht
```

but even that's more spoken than written language.

```
Wir haben es leider gestern nicht mehr geschafft
```

is probably most correct.

Comment: If you were to translate it with "ausreichen", then I'd make the time explicit: "Die Zeit hat gestern leider nicht mehr gereicht." "Es hat nicht gereicht" sounds very strange to me.

Answer (score -1):

I would agree that `es hat sich ausgegangen` is the correct present perfect tense of `es geht sich aus`. I also strongly agree that `sich ausgehen` is very regional and only being used by a certain group of speakers. That group does not include myself. I would understand it vaguely, but I would struggle to understand what the *exact* meaning is. I am from the Dortmund area. It might be correct that it's chiefly used in the southern parts of the German speaking area. I would use `Es hat nicht geklappt`. As far as I remember, I never heard `sich ausgehen` in any official TV news show or such. I agree it's mostly spoken language *and* limited to a certain group of speakers.

Comment: The original question is not at all about the meaning or the use of _sich ausgehen_ but only about the correct auxiliary when forming the Perfekt tense.

Answer (score -4):

"sich ausgehen"

this phrase doesn't exist in german.

neither the answer of Stefan Walter is correct.

lsiten to pilif he is absolutely right!

Comment: The phrase *definitely* exists, even if its now known everywhere.

Comment: according to Duden: "Es geht sich aus: österreichisch umgangssprachlich für *es reicht gerade*."